# Eloquent LIKE statement with setBindings not returning results

Tags: eloquent

I am new to Laravel.  This query below works perfectly and gives me the results I expect:

```
  $keywords = 'e';
  $pages = DB::table('page_translations')
    ->select('page_translations.id')
    ->where([
      ['page_translations.title','LIKE','%'.$keywords.'%'],
    ])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

However, it is not clear to me if my query above is susceptible to SQL injection.  So I decided to use setBindings as shown in the query below:

```
  $keywords = 'e';
  $pages = DB::table('page_translations')
    ->select('page_translations.id')
    ->where([
      ['page_translations.title','LIKE','%?%'],
    ])
    ->setBindings([$keywords])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

However, this query with `setBindings` returns zero results.  What did I do wrong?  Why does it not behave like the query above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is correct and **not** susceptible to SQL injections.

Typically, you would write it like this:

```php
->where('page_translations.title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keywords.'%')
```